# How to get file size always in GB

Tags: shell, unix

```
du -sh myfile.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'
250.10M
```

how to get the size of a file always in "GB" even if its size is in few KB or MB or TB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell `du` to output the sizes in bytes (`-b` flag), and then use awk for the division:

```
du -bs myfile.txt | awk '{$1=$1/2^30"GB"}1'
```

Or to just get the sizes, and not the names, use

```
du -bs myfile.txt | awk '{print $1/2^30}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ll file_name | awk '{print $5/2^30}'
```

Or

```
bc -l <<< "scale=15;$(ll file_name| cut -d' ' -f5 )/1073741824"
```